# open sqlite file swift osx app and read data

Tags: macos, sqlite, swift

I need to open a sqlite file and read data from that file to show in a table. 
So far I have a button that trigger NSOpenPanel(), and get the path. After that I tried to open the file but I have an encoding problem.

Below my code in the AppDelegate.swift

```
@IBAction func importFromKobo(sender: AnyObject) {
 var openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    let fileDB = "kobodbtest.sqlite"

    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in
        if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
            //Do what you will
            //If there's only one URL, surely 'openPanel.URL'
            var deviceURL = openPanel.URL!
            println("Path: \(deviceURL)")
            println(self.resultDev.stringValue)
            self.resultDev.stringValue += "\nPath: \(deviceURL)"
            self.resultInput.stringValue += "\nPath: \(deviceURL)"
            var fullFilePathURL = deviceURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileDB)
            self.resultInput.stringValue += "\nFull path file: \(fullFilePathURL)"

            var fileOpenError:NSError?

            if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(deviceURL.path!) {
                println("file OK")


                if let fileContent = String(contentsOfURL: fullFilePathURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &fileOpenError) {
                    println(fileContent)        // prints ReadMe.txt contents if successful
                } else {
                    if let fileOpenError = fileOpenError {
                    println(fileOpenError)  // Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=XXX "The file “ReadMe.txt” couldn’t be opened because...."
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("file not found")
            }

        }
        if result == NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton {
            self.resultDev.stringValue = "Cancel"
        }

    }

}`
```

And the error in the console:

```
Path: file:///Users/alvaroruiz/Documents/xcode/
Result
file OK
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file “kobodbtest.sqlite” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo=0x60000026cb00 {NSFilePath=/Users/alvaroruiz/Documents/xcode/kobodbtest.sqlite, NSStringEncoding=4}
```

I have checked usign `sqlite> PRAGMA encoding;` that the format is UTF-8.

Checked with other encoding like NSISOLatin1StringEncoding and get the text but with a lot of symbols.

Could you also point me how to do the query command? and display in a table?

Thanks.
Alvaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if the path you just selected exists, it's unnecessary. I guess you wanted to check for the final file instead:

```
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fullFilePathURL.path!)
```

Next, Leonardo was right in his comment, you *can* read the file by using `NSUTF16StringEncoding`:

```
if let fileContent = String(contentsOfURL: fullFilePathURL, encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding, error: &fileOpenError) {
```

But an sqlite database is not a text file, and just reading the plain content as text won't get you very far. :) So you should rather use a dedicated tool to deal with it, like [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift). This will allow you to run queries and display the results in a table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already had SQLite.swift bookmarked, just going slowly. I changed the file path check, and it works.